# Angular Momentum Conservation in Gravitational Interaction

Tags: gravity, angular-momentum, momentum, torque

thanks for any help.

I'm trying to show that in a 2body problem, angular momentum is conserved given that $\dfrac{dp}{dt}=\dfrac{-GMm(rv)}{r³}$, where p is momentum, t time, G gravitational constant, M mass of 1 object, m mass of the other, (rv) is the vector between them and r is the magnitude of the vector between them.

I've had a lot of attempts but I don't seem to get very far.

Where L is angular momentum, $r_1$ is position vector of mass M and $r_2$ is position vector of mass m, $p_1$ is momentum of mass M and $p_2$ is momentum of mass m.

L=$r_1Xp_1+r_2Xp_2$

If $\dfrac{dL}{dt}=0$ then dL will be conserved over time, applying product rule
            $L=\dfrac{dr_1}{dt}Xp_1+r_1X\dfrac{dp_1}{dt}+\dfrac{dr_2}{dt}Xp_2+r_2X\dfrac{dp_2}{dt}$

noticing that $p_1=m\dfrac{dr_1}{dt}$ and $p_2=m\dfrac{dr_2}{dt}$ clearly $p_1$ is parallel to$ \dfrac{dr_1}{dt}$ and $p_2$ is parallel to $\dfrac{dr_2}{dt}$ and hence when cross producted with them, the result is 0.

Giving $L=r_1X\dfrac{dp_1}{dt}+r_2X\dfrac{dp_2}{dt}$

I gather I must now show that either these two terms are 0, or they are equal and     opposite. I can't see any reason why they would be 0, and (slightly guessing) it seems to    make sense to me that they are terms related to how the angular momentum of one body changes    with the other body, and I assume they must therefore be equal and opposite. However when I    do

$r_1X\dfrac{dp_1}{dt}=-r_2X\dfrac{dp_2}{dt}$
     I notice $\dfrac{dp_1}{dt}=\dfrac{-GMm(rv)}{r³}$ and $\dfrac{dp_2}{dt}=\dfrac{GMm(rv)}{r³}$ (since (rv)'s direction is flipped)
    Therefore $r_1X\dfrac{-GMm(rv)}{r³}=-\dfrac{r_2XGMm(rv)}{r³}$
    Defining $w=\dfrac{GMm}{r³}$:

$r_1X(rv)(-w)=r_2X(rv)(-w)$

Scalar products are commutative so the (-w)'s easily cancel giving

$r_1X(rv)=r_2X(rv)$
 Which then the only solutions are if all components of $r_1$ are equal to all components of      $r_2$, however angular momentum should clearly be conserved in all positions, not just when the masses are ontop of each other.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. You will be much more likely to get responses to your questions if you format your math properly: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Does this SE answer give you what you want? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29737/

Comment: Thank you Ben, I will try to reformat it.

And no BMS as that's a single body problem.

Comment: The two-body problem reduces to a single-body problem, because the center of mass doesn't accelerate. In the two-body problem, the two angular momenta aren't equal, and they don't cancel. They're separately conserved, since each body is acted on by a central force that produces no torque. This sounds like homework, so I'm going to put the homework tag on it. If it's not homework, please remove the tag. If I'm right and it is homework, then please add the tag yourself in the future.

Comment: I can't see how they're conserved seperately, if a mass for instance comes towards a planet but misses it, it will slingshot off and curve, its angular momentum changing.

Comment: Hi user2836596. It seems that @Ben Crowell is correct in adding the homework tag. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I don't want to get in an edit war over this homework tag, but user2836596, rather than just reverting my addition of the tag without explanation, it would have been better to explain what's up. Phrases like "I gather I must now show that ..." sound like this is homework.

Comment: I'm not particularly bothered (nor can I think of any reason you are either?), put it back if you like it doesn't matter in the slightest. I was just doing exactly what you said which was " If it's not homework, please remove the tag." If you don't want me to remove it when it's not homework, then don't say that.

I don't see how phrases like "I gather I must now show that..." make it sound like homework. It makes it sound like it's something that must clearly be the case, since dL/dt must be 0. I'm trying to show to myself angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: As it is something that is often touted but I've never seen a derivation of it, so I'm trying to derive it in a simple interaction since I imagine a general proof is beyond me, as I have attempted to look up a general proof and seen things such as Noether's theorem which I do not understand.

Though it no longer matters, I've managed to figure it out.