# Deriving the equation for Angular Momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum

The equation for angular momentum is L=mvr in which L is the angular momentum, m is the mass, v is the velocity, r is the radius.  How does one derive this equation from the other laws of motion?

Comment: This, you might say is the definition of angular momentum. More generally it is $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$. When a particular is moving along a circle, then the angular momentum about the center of the circle reduces to $|\vec{L}| = L = mvr$.

Comment: You can understand angular momentum conservation as a consequence of isotropy of space, see Noether's theorem (or, more specialized, in systems with radial potential), but that's a slightly different matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136588/, should be helpful even if not.